# Oracle SQL Combine Two Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
with rws as (
    select c.ID as P_ID, c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME as PATIENT, to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') as SESSION_MONTH,
    to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as SESSION_DATE,
        row_number () over (
            partition by CLIENTS_ID
            order by c.ID asc
        ) rn
    from   SESSIONS s inner join CLIENTS c
    on c.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
    where c.ACTIVE = 2
)
  select * from rws
  where  rn <= 1
  order  by P_ID asc;
```

with this result:
[image]

Also i have this query:

```
select c.ID as P_ID, c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME as PATIENT, count(s.Id) as Qty, sum(s.AMOUNT) as PAID,
sum(s.PRICE-s.AMOUNT) as Dif
from SESSIONS s inner join CLIENTS c
on c.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
where c.ACTIVE =2
and s.STATUS = 5
group by c.ID, c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME
order by P_ID;
```

with this result:
[image]

The patient id is the same for both queries.
Is it possible to combine this two queries to one and to have this result?

[image]

Thanks to @Sam Ware this is the correct query:

```
with rws as (
    select p.ID as P_ID, p.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || p.LAST_NAME as PATIENT, to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') as SESSION_MONTH,
    to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as SESSION_DATE,
        row_number () over (
            partition by CLIENTS_ID
            order by p.ID asc
        ) rn
    from   SESSIONS s inner join CLIENTS p
    on p.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
    where p.ACTIVE = 2
), transactions as (
    select p.ID as P_ID, count(s.Id) as Qty, sum(s.AMOUNT) as PAID,
        sum(s.PRICE-s.AMOUNT) as Dif
    from SESSIONS s inner join CLIENTS p
        on p.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
    where p.ACTIVE =2
        and s.STATUS = 5
    group by p.ID
    order by P_ID
)
  select r.*, t.Qty, t.PAID, t.Dif
  from rws r
  inner join transactions t
    on r.p_id = t.p_id
  where r.rn <= 1
  order by r.P_ID asc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with rws as (
    select c.ID as P_ID, c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME as PATIENT, to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') as SESSION_MONTH,
    to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as SESSION_DATE,
        row_number () over (
            partition by CLIENTS_ID
            order by c.ID asc
        ) rn
    from   SESSIONS s inner join CLIENTS c
    on c.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
    where c.ACTIVE = 2
), paid_stats as (
    select c.ID as P_ID, c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME as PATIENT, count(s.Id) as Qty, sum(s.AMOUNT) as PAID,
        sum(s.PRICE-s.AMOUNT) as Dif
    from SESSIONS s inner join CLIENTS c
        on c.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
    where c.ACTIVE =2
        and s.STATUS = 5
    group by c.ID, c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME
    order by P_ID
),
  select rws.*, paid_stats.Qty, paid_stats.PAID, paid_stats.Dif
  from rws
  join paid_stats 
    on rws.p_id = paid.p_id
  where  rn <= 1
  order  by P_ID asc;
```

Comment: Hello @Sam and thank you for your response. When i run your query, i get this error: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Comment: I found it! I changed the name of the second table (paid) that you create because we have this name as a column and i removed an extra comma. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not give any sample data so this is difficult to test but you can use conditional aggregation in analytic functions:

```sql
with rws as (
  select c.ID as P_ID,
         c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME as PATIENT,
         to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') as SESSION_MONTH,
         to_char(s.SESSION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as SESSION_DATE,
         ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTS_ID ORDER BY c.ID ASC) AS rn,
         COUNT(CASE s.STATUS WHEN 5 THEN s.ID)
           OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID) AS Qty,
         SUM(CASE s.STATUS WHEN 5 THEN s.AMOUNT)
           OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID) AS Paid,
         SUM(CASE s.STATUS WHEN 5 THEN s.PRICE - s.AMOUNT)
           OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID) AS DIF
  from   SESSIONS s
         inner join CLIENTS c
         on c.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
  where c.ACTIVE = 2
)
SELECT *
FROM   rws
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER BY P_ID asc;
```

*Note: This assumes that `c.ID` is the primary key and it is not necessary to include the name in the `PARTITION BY` clause; if it is necessary then you need to add it in [and look at your data model to see if it can be improved]).*